# RxJs How do deal with document events

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Started using RxJs. Can't find a way around this problem. I have a draggable control:

```
startDrag = rx.Observable.fromEvent(myElem,'mousedown')
```

now, because the control is too small `mousemove` and `mouseup` events should be at document level (otherwise it won't stop dragging unless cursor exactly on the element)

```
endDrag = rx.Observable.fromEvent document,'mouseup'

position = startDrag.flatMap ->
   rx.Observable.fromEvent document,'mousemove'
   .map (x)-> x.clientX
   .takeUntil endDrag
```

now how do I "catch" the right moment when is not being dragged anymore (`mouseup`). 
you see the problem with subscribing to `endDrag`? It will fire every time clicked anywhere, and not just `myElem`
How do I check all 3 properties at once? It should take only those document.mouseups that happened exactly after `startDrag` and `position`

**Upd**: I mean the problem is not with moving the element. That part is easy - subscribe to `position`, change element's css. 
My problem is - I need to detect the moment of `mouseup` and know the exact element that's been dragged (there are multiple elements on the page). How to do that I have no idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have adapted the [drag and drop example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/dragndrop/dragndrop.js) provided at the RxJS repo to behave as you need.

### Notable changes:

- `mouseUp` listens at `document`.
- The targeted element is added to the return from `select`.
- Drag movements are handled inside of `map` and `map` returns the element that was targeted in the `mouseDown` event.
- Call [`last`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/last.md) after `takeUntil(mouseUp)` so `subscribe` will only be reached when the drag process ends (once per drag).

### Working example:

```js
function main() {
  var dragTarget = document.getElementById('dragTarget');

  // Get the three major events
  var mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
  var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
  var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');


  var mousedrag = mousedown.selectMany(function(md) {

    // calculate offsets when mouse down
    var startX = md.offsetX;
    var startY = md.offsetY;

    // Calculate delta with mousemove until mouseup
    return mousemove.select(function(mm) {
      if (mm.preventDefault) mm.preventDefault();
      else event.returnValue = false;

      return {
        // Include the targeted element
        elem: mm.target,
        pos: {
          left: mm.clientX - startX,
          top: mm.clientY - startY
        }
      };
    })
    .map(function(data) {
      // Update position
      dragTarget.style.top = data.pos.top + 'px';
      dragTarget.style.left = data.pos.left + 'px';

      // Just return the element
      return data.elem;
    })
    .takeUntil(mouseup)
    .last();
  });


  // Here we receive the element when the drag is finished
  subscription = mousedrag.subscribe(function(elem) {
    alert('Drag ended on #' + elem.id);
  });
}
main();
```

```css
#dragTarget {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.7/rx.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragTarget"></div>
```

Comment: Wow... thank you Jon! This seems to be working for me incredibly well. Heck. Rx could be really confusing for starters...

Comment: yeah the key is that you put the `takeUntil()` *inside* the `flatMap` instead of after, so that it is applied to individual drags instead of the overall observable

Comment: @Agzam glad you found it helpful. I enjoy digging into these sorts of problems :)

Comment: @VishalSakaria yeah! You can do some really cool stuff with Rx.