# Plunker giving me 404s on scripts that worked a several days ago

Tags: javascript, angular, jsx, plunker

I made a plunker a few weeks ago and everything was going well.

However today when I revisited it I am bombarded by 404s on my scripts, any idea on what changed?

http://plnkr.co/edit/M2hRaf?p=preview

[image: Chrome console output]
Here is what the index.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="." />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker = 'latest'
    </script>
    <title>angular playground</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app')
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>
      Loading...
    </my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because your plunker now uses latest rxjs version and there were a lot of changes lately.

So try updating your config like:

```
System.config({
  ...
  map: {
    ...,
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'rxjs-compat': 'npm:rxjs-compat',
    'rxjs/operators': 'npm:rxjs/operators',
  },
  packages: {
    ...,
    'rxjs': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs/operators': {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  }
  ...
```

**[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iAJ4ZS?p=preview)**

Comment: Ah, here I thought my scripts references got changed, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

use this for updating rxjs version in your plunker `'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.2',` instead of `'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',` in your config.js file